# Alternate syntax in XAML for applying attached property

Tags: wpf, xaml, attached-properties

How do I re-write the following XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding NewSalesOrderCommand}" Content="New Order" Width="50" />
```

So that I could use an attached property on the Command object:

```
<Button Content="New Order" Width="50">
    <Button.Command local:MyClass.MyAttachedProp="1">
        ...
    </Button.Command>
</Button>
```

means what appears in place of 3 dots?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, try the following

```
<Button Content="New Order" Width="50">
    <Button.Command local:MyClass.MyAttachedProp="1">
        <Binding Path="NewSalesOrderCommand" />
    </Button.Command>
</Button>
```

For more information, pls have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx).

Comment: Results in error. "Cannot set properties on property elements."

Comment: Did you try it without your `AttachedProperty`?

Comment: Works without attached property. So is there no XAML way of applying an attached property here?

Comment: Well let me have a look on the implementation of the `AttachedProperty`. Perhaps there is a minor issue.

Comment: @dotNET By thinking about it. No, you cannot assign an `AttachedProperty` this way. You can only assign it to a specific instance of a class but not to a property. You could create a wrapper for the commands, which could be inititalized in the XAML and bound to e.g. _NewSalesOrderCommand_. But this seems to be a huge overhead. Perhaps you should reconsider your approach. What's the intention behind this `AttachedProperty`?

Comment: A little role-based security system that I designed using a few attached properties. All elements get configured correctly except the Buttons, which take their IsEnabled state from their Commands even when u specify it explicitly in the Style. I was able to get around it by specifying the value of attached property in the code-behind. Thanks a bunch for your effort.